# Записать данные в файл, по заданному количеству столбцов

Tags: c#, файлы

Нужна помощь. У меня есть файл, в котором в два столбца записаны числа, в первом столбце номер числа, во втором само число:

```
000001 9780000000019  
000002 9780000000026  
000003 9780000000033  
000004 9780000000040
```

Мне нужно разбить их на столбцы, количество которых ввожу в начале работы программы. т.е, если ввожу 3 столбца, должно получиться так :

```
000001 000003 000005 9780000000019 9780000000033 9780000000057  
000002 000004 000006 9780000000026 9780000000040 9780000000064
```

Я считал из файла все числа и записал их в два массива , один с номерами, а другой с числами, но что делать дальше понять не могу.

```
    int num = int.Parse(textBox3.Text); //количество столбцов
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(target);
    string[] a = reader.ReadToEnd().Split('\t','\r','\n'); 
    string[] numbers = new string[1000000]; // массив номеров
    string[] values = new string[1000000]; // массив значений
    int _N = 0;
    int N=0;
    for (int z = 0; z <= a.Length-2; z += 3)
    {
        numbers[N] = a[z];
        N += 1;
    }
    for (int z = 1; z <= a.Length - 1; z += 3)
    {
        values[_N] = a[z];
        _N += 1;
    }
    reader.Close();
```

Comment: Получилось так, что все данные записываются в  строки, в порядке "номер" "число" "номер" "число", а мне необходима запись в виде 
"номер" "номер" "номер" "число" "число" "число" ... @Максим

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int num = int.Parse(textBox3.Text); //количество столбцов
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(target);
string[] a = reader.ReadToEnd().Split('\t','\r','\n'); 
string[] numbers = new string[1000000]; // массив номеров
string[] values = new string[1000000]; // массив значений
int _N = 0;
int N=0;
for (int z = 0; z <= a.Length-2; z += 3)
{
    numbers[N] = a[z];
    N += 1;
}
for (int z = 1; z <= a.Length - 1; z += 3)
{
    values[_N] = a[z];
    _N += 1;
}
reader.Close();

StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(target2);
int columns = num;
int rows = numbers.Length / columns;
for (int r = 0; r <= rows-1; r++){
    for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++){
        writer.Write(numbers[(rows * c) + r]);
        writer.Write('\t');
    }
    for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++){
        writer.Write(values[(rows * c) + r]);
        if(c < (columns - 1)){
            writer.Write('\t');
        }
    }
    writer.Write('\r');
}
writer.Close();
```